# how can i trim string between xml tag with sed?

Tags: xml, awk, sed, trim, substitution

I need to remove blank spaces between two pattern. Input file is xml. I need to keep xml format.
I've this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abc d e</column>
    <column> fg </column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">08 4 </cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">006</cell>
      <cell id="2"> AL</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">042 </cell>
      <cell id="2">AN  </cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
```

I'd like to have below output using sed command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abcde</column>
    <column>fg</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">084</cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">006</cell>
      <cell id="2">AL</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">042</cell>
      <cell id="2">AN</cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, for anything else you should be using awk.

If your XML is really that well-formed:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)(>[^<]+)(.*)/,a) { $0 = a[1] gensub(/ /,"","g",a[2]) a[3] } 1' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abcde</column>
    <column>fg</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">084</cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">006</cell>
      <cell id="2">AL</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">042</cell>
      <cell id="2">AN</cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `gensub()`, with other awks you'd use `substr()`, a temp variable, and `gsub()`:

```
$ awk '
match($0,/>[^<]+/) {
    t = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/ /,"",t)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) t substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abcde</column>
    <column>fg</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">084</cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">006</cell>
      <cell id="2">AL</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">042</cell>
      <cell id="2">AN</cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
```

wrt your followup question, to only trim leading/trailing blanks would be:

```
$ awk '
match($0,/>[^<]+/) {
    t = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",t)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART) t substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1' file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abcde</column>
    <column>fg</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">08 4</cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">00 6</cell>
      <cell id="2">AL</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">0 42</cell>
      <cell id="2">AN</cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
```

Comment: tnx Ed for your reply. can you help me with below request? thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank You so much Ed, tomorrow I will try your workaround

Comment: You're welcome. It's not a workaround, though, it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Is possibile to count blanks between ">"  and the first occurrence of char/digit and/or between last char/digit and "</" with awk command?

Comment: Of course. Anything is possible in software. Post a new question if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, Ed. The above command works like a sharm!

```
 awk '
match($0,/>[^<]+/) {
    t = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/ /,"",t)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) t substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1' file
```

I've another question. How can i solve if i want delete blanks only between the '>' and first occurrence of other char, and the same for the last occurrence of a char and the '<' char?

If my input now is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abcde</column>
    <column>fg</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1"> 08 4      </cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">    00 6        </cell>
      <cell id="2">   AL   </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">0 42 </cell>
      <cell id="2">AN  </cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
```

how can i have the below result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dvm name="Filename" xml="http://www.google.it">
  <description>AL</description>
  <columns>
    <column>abcde</column>
    <column>fg</column>
  </columns>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">08 4</cell>
      <cell id="2">AG</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">00 6</cell>
      <cell id="2">AL</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell id="1">0 42</cell>
      <cell id="2">AN</cell>
    </row>
   </rows>
```